# C Updating text file using r+ mode

Tags: c, file-io, fopen, stdio, mode

I have a text file. I want to update it, that is reading some text until a certain place and then writing some new text that overrides the new text. For example, my
text file content is : "abc".
If I open the file in r+ mode and only use the reading options or if I only use the writing options then it works just fine. However, if I write a program like this:

```
void main()
{
    FILE* myFile = fopen("myFile.txt", "r+");
    fgetc(myFile);
    fprintf(myFile, "d");
    fclose(myFile);
}
```

What I expected the text file to look like was: "adc" but It stayed as "abc". The reading worked, but it seems that the writing didn't work. In addition, if I write this program:

```
void main()
{
    FILE* myFile = fopen("myFile.txt", "r+");
    fprintf(myFile, "d");
    fgetc(myFile);
    fclose(myFile);
}
```

The program will finish with the VS message: "File Load - some bytes have been placed with the unicode substitution character while loading the file". And there is like a question mark symbol where the b was. The solution I found is before switching from writing to reading and vice versa, was to just call:

```
fseek(myFile, ftell(myFile), SEEK_SET);
```

Everytime before switching from writing to reading and vice versa,
And it will work properly. But why does this solution work? And what is wrong in the first two examples or in my way of thinking?

Comment: Did you read the [manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html)? It is expected behaviour. "*Reads and writes may be intermixed on read/write streams in any order.  Note that ANSI C requires that a file positioning function intervene between output and input, unless an input operation encounters end-of-file.  (If this condition is not met, then a read is allowed to return the result of writes other than the most recent.)  Therefore it is good practice (and indeed sometimes necessary under Linux) to put an fseek(3) or fgetpos(3) operation between write and read operations*"

Comment: @kaylum I am not using linux, and fseek(3) and fgetpos(3) don't work. But thanks for the information.

Comment: It says ANSI C. That applies to more than Linux.